# sourcecode problem at enum

Tags: c#

Goal:
Assign an enum value to the animalType object.

> Categories.CategoryType animalType =
>   (CategoryType)Enum.Parse(GetType(CategoryType),
>   pCategory);

Problem:
The source code does not work properly and it gives me two error messages:

> "Assignment1.Categories.CategoryType' is a 'type' but is used like a
>   'variable'"
>
> "No overload for method 'GetType' takes 1 arguments"

```
namespace Assignment1
{
    class AnimalManager
    {
        private List<IAnimal> _myAnimal = new List<IAnimal>();

        public void CreateNewAnimal(string pName, string pHousing, string pAge, string pCategory, string pAnimal, string pEater, string pGender)
        {
            Categories.CategoryType animalType = (CategoryType)Enum.Parse(GetType(CategoryType), pCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment1.Categories
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public enum CategoryType
    {
        Mammal,
        Bird,
        Marine,
        Reptile,
        Insect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Categories.CategoryType animalType =
    (CategoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CategoryType), pCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
CategoryType animalType = 
    (CategoryType)Enum.Parse(typeof(CategoryType), pCategory);
```

When you need the type of something you know statically (at compile time), use the `typeof` operator. The `GetType` method is meant for runtime type information in cases of polymorphism (in which case you'd do something like `pCategory.GetType`). Lastly note that `Enum.Parse` can throw - So you might want to take a look at [Enum.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx.).